# Logging Activities: How to record time using a PHP application?

Tags: php, mysql, session, logging, tracking

I'm working with some existing PHP/MySQL code. I'm logging/tracking certain activities into a MySQL database. Certain access points are being logged. The number of times a user logs-into the system is counted. But, I need to also log the amount of time a user is logged-in, as well as the time the user is in a certain section of the Web site.

Since PHP is a stateless environment, for the most part, what's the best way to record the end-point(s); or when the user logs-out?

Note: I can't force the user to log out, as the browser can just be closed. Maybe I could just put up an AJAX timer that would count the minutes? If so, should I treat activities and time logged-in as different tables of information (MySQL)?

Edit: I forgot to mention we do have jQuery available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, you can't force the user to logout, and you can't know for sure whether he's looking at your page or playing Pinball.

A solution would be an AJAX request every, say 5 minutes, to tell your application that the user is active. Unfortunately, if your user has locked his screen and went to play Pinball, you still don't know exactly what he is doing. Also, doing AJAX requests at intervals like this will increase server load, especially in a multi-user environment.

The best solution I think is to simply store the `start_time` of the user (when he logs in), then to update the `end_time` at every action he does, and with a session timeout.

Per example:

- I log in at 5:00. Update the `start_time` to `5:00`.
- I browse to `foo.php` at 5:01. Update the `end_time` to `5:01`.
- I browse to `bar.php` at 5:03. Update the `end_time` to `5:03`.
- I go for a coffee at 5:05.
- I come back at 5:15 and my session expired, I need to relogin.

So, you know I spent roughly 3 minutes on your application, since the last action I did was at 5:03 (`5:03 - 5:00 = 3`). Of course, you can't know exactly if it was 3 or 5 minutes. But you can assume, most of the times anyway, that if I don't do anything on your application (i.e.: execute a script, call, etc.), that I'm not using it.

Obviously, if you can capture JavaScript events like *window close* it's even better, or if I sign out manually: you update the `end_time` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture two events.

1. The onCLose() event for the page and hook that into an ajax call back to your logging system.
2. The onClick() event for your logout button and hook it into the save ajax handler.

The onClose event will allow you to capture when either the tab/broswer is closed and the onCLick event is obvious.

Now this will not capture times when the browser dies, the machine loses power etc. so there will be instances where you will have gaps and those can be corrected by your login event handler and simply tag the last login event as logout out on the next login.  This will however lead to outliers in your tracking of time spent logged in and you will need to statistically deal with those in your reporting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extra PHP script that records the last activity and call it via ajax.

You can use javascript to monitor if the user is still active (moved mouse or pressed a key in the last 5 minutes etc.)

EDIT: Almost forgot the important part: your java script must make an ajax request eery X seconds.
So if there was no request in x+tollerance seconds you can consider the session as dead.